# How come I've been ripped of 15 points?

Tags: discussion

[What happened to "accented velars" in Anatolian?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34196/what-happened-to-accented-velars-in-anatolian/34200#34200)
What's going on here??
How come I'm down 15 points??
I'd like some explanation.

Comment: Hm. I was going to vote to migrate this to Meta, but that option seems to no longer exist. When did that change?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a meta question to be discussed on meta and not on the main site.

Comment: I'm voting to migrate it. Did you not find the button?

Comment: @user6726 Ah, now I see it. Seems I was just blind for a minute.

Answer (score 6):

Your answer's completely correct, but I found Melchert's description of the developments in Luvian more conclusive—the fact that **k* and **ḱ* have reliably different reflexes in one Anatolian language seems like good proof that they remained distinct in Proto-Anatolian, even if Kloekhorst says they merged in Hittite. So I moved the accepted checkmark.

(I've still upvoted your answer, though, and I don't disagree with any part of it. If you want to add the Luvian evidence to yours, or argue that Melchert's wrong about it, feel free to!)